# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getSystemService

Tags: android-jobscheduler

I am trying to implement a jobscheduler to call jobservice, which triggers in every 5 minute to capture the time spent in a particular geoLocation. but the below code is working for Marshmallow and above, but its making crash for lollipop and below.
this is my code->

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, SyncDbToServerJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.ENTERED_TIME, enteredTime);
        builder.setPeriodic(intervalMillis).setExtras(bundle).setPersisted(true);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

this like making an error->

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
```

this is my log error->

```
04-19 11:38:25.358 1986-4658/com.eonelectric.eon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GeofenceTransitionsIS]
                                                               Process: com.eonelectric.eon, PID: 1986
                                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getSystemService(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Landroid/content/Context; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.Context' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
                                                                   at com.eonelectric.eon.GeneralUtil.startSyncAlarm(GeneralUtil.java:440)
                                                                   at com.eonelectric.eon.beatTrack.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:137)
                                                                   at com.eonelectric.eon.beatTrack.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.onHandleIntent(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:96)
                                                                   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue you got any solution for that ?

Comment: i am using AlarmManager for below lollipop(API 21), and JobScheduler for Marshmallow and above. now its not crashing. but still JobScheduler is not triggering the service in exact time(5 Minute), may be OS killing the background thread. and AlarmManager is draining battery too much. @Jordon

Comment: For me JobScheduler is  working on marshmallow i tried with 10 second interval and its working fine.Did you check the job scheduler on Android N ?. For me Job is getting called only once in Android N.

Comment: No, for me it's triggering service, but not in specified time and regular interval, there is inconsistency in triggering service. like any time, when it's getting CPU(WAKE LOCK) free or may be, it's because of DOZE(Sleep) mode. i don't know exactly, but still i am struggling with same issue since 2 weeks.

Comment: I am also looking for this solution from last few days . please let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: Sure, i will. @Jordon

Answer (score 2):

Try this one it will work for lollipop

```
ComponentName jobService =
                new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), SyncService.class.getName());
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, jobService);
builder.setPeriodic(10000);
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) this.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Comment: may be it will work. but JobScheduler launched to handle DOZE Mode issue and Doze mode came in Marshmallow/Nougat. so i am handling code using -  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 21){
                        GeneralUtil.startSyncAlarmLollipop(context, enteredTime);
                    } else {
                        GeneralUtil.startSyncAlarm(context, enteredTime);
                    }

Comment: GeneralUtil.startSyncAlarmLollipop(context, enteredTime)- in this method, i am using AlarmManager with PendingIntent to call BroadcastReceiver.     GeneralUtil.startSyncAlarm(context, enteredTime)- in this method, i am using JobScheduler.

Answer (score 2):

If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or more, Google recommends that you use the `[JobScheduler][1]` to execute background tasks, but `[getSystemService(serviceClass)][2]` was added in API level 23. So, use like:

```
 JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE)
```

to also include API 21 and 22.